# Enable textbox based on input

Tags: javascript

I have 2 sets of textboxes (1,2,3,4) and (a,b,c,d,e,f). All of these are numerical inputs

I'm using javascript to disable 6 textboxes (a,b,c,d,e,f) at onload and it's working well.

But I want to enable the 6 textboxes once a value > 0 is input into textbox (3)

I try to use onChange but it does not work.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () { 
var td2 = document.getElementsByName('A1ab1')[0]; 
td2.disabled = true;  
var td2 = document.getElementsByName('A1ab2')[0]; 
td2.disabled = true;
var td3 = document.getElementsByName('A1ab3')[0]; 
td3.disabled = true;
var td4 = document.getElementsByName('A1ab4')[0]; 
td4.disabled = true;
var td5 = document.getElementsByName('A1ab5')[0]; 
td5.disabled = true;
var td6 = document.getElementsByName('A1ab6')[0]; 
td6.disabled = true;
var td7 = document.getElementsByName('A1a3')[0];
td7.onChange = function(){
var x = document.getElementsByName('A1a3')[0].value;
    if(x > 0){
                td1.disabled = false;
                td2.disabled = false;
                td3.disabled = false;
                td4.disabled = false;
                td5.disabled = false;
                td6.disabled = false;                    
    }       
}   
}
</script>
<body>
<table border="0" class="NumericTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr class="r1"><td class="item"><span class="OptionFont">1</span></td><td class="text"><input type=text class=text name="A1a1" value="" size=9 maxlength=9 style="text-align:right" onkeyup="{showTotalA1a(); }"   onkeypress="return checkNumericValue(event)"  onBlur="Javascript:onBlurUpdate(this);"  /></td></tr>
<tr class="r2"><td class="item"><span class="OptionFont">2</span></td><td class="text"><input type=text class=text name="A1a2" value="" size=9 maxlength=9 style="text-align:right" onkeyup="{showTotalA1a(); }"   onkeypress="return checkNumericValue(event)"  onBlur="Javascript:onBlurUpdate(this);"  /></td></tr>
<tr class="r1"><td class="item"><span class="OptionFont">3</span></td><td class="text"><input type=text class=text name="A1a3" value="" size=9 maxlength=9 style="text-align:right" onkeyup="{showTotalA1a(); }"   onkeypress="return checkNumericValue(event)"  onBlur="Javascript:onBlurUpdate(this);"  /></td></tr>
<tr class="r2"><td class="item"><span class="OptionFont">4</span></td><td class="text"><input type=text class=text name="A1a4" value="" size=9 maxlength=9 style="text-align:right" onkeyup="{showTotalA1a(); }"   onkeypress="return checkNumericValue(event)"  onBlur="Javascript:onBlurUpdate(this);"  /></td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<table border="0" class="NumericTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr class="r1"><td class="item"><span class="OptionFont">a</span></td><td class="text"><input type=text class=text name="A1ab1" value="" size=9 maxlength=9 style="text-align:right" onkeyup="{showTotalA1ab(); }"   onkeypress="return checkNumericValue(event)"  onBlur="Javascript:onBlurUpdate(this);"  /></td></tr>
<tr class="r2"><td class="item"><span class="OptionFont">b</span></td><td class="text"><input type=text class=text name="A1ab2" value="" size=9 maxlength=9 style="text-align:right" onkeyup="{showTotalA1ab(); }"   onkeypress="return checkNumericValue(event)"  onBlur="Javascript:onBlurUpdate(this);"  /></td></tr>
<tr class="r1"><td class="item"><span class="OptionFont">c</span></td><td class="text"><input type=text class=text name="A1ab3" value="" size=9 maxlength=9 style="text-align:right" onkeyup="{showTotalA1ab(); }"   onkeypress="return checkNumericValue(event)"  onBlur="Javascript:onBlurUpdate(this);"  /></td></tr>
<tr class="r2"><td class="item"><span class="OptionFont">d</span></td><td class="text"><input type=text class=text name="A1ab4" value="" size=9 maxlength=9 style="text-align:right" onkeyup="{showTotalA1ab(); }"   onkeypress="return checkNumericValue(event)"  onBlur="Javascript:onBlurUpdate(this);"  /></td></tr>
<tr class="r1"><td class="item"><span class="OptionFont">e</span></td><td class="text"><input type=text class=text name="A1ab5" value="" size=9 maxlength=9 style="text-align:right" onkeyup="{showTotalA1ab(); }"   onkeypress="return checkNumericValue(event)"  onBlur="Javascript:onBlurUpdate(this);"  /></td></tr>
<tr class="r2"><td class="item"><span class="OptionFont">f</span></td><td class="text"><input type=text class=text name="A1ab6" value="" size=9 maxlength=9 style="text-align:right" onkeyup="{showTotalA1ab(); }"   onkeypress="return checkNumericValue(event)"  onBlur="Javascript:onBlurUpdate(this);"  /></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
jQuery('#some_text_box').on('input', function() {
   // do your stuff
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6bSX6/)

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined variable "td1." Highly recommend using the browser's javascript console to debug stuff like this. It should produce an error when onChange is executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JQuery try using .onkeydown instead of .onchange.

Also, you'll probably need to parse the int value from the text box:

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('A1a3')[0].value);
```